# Possibility of publishing

Tags: soft-question, publishing

First little background. I have master degree in mathematics. Then I decided to continue to study PhD level. After some years I cancel study (reason was in some things in my life). Now I am returning back to mathematics. I have job, but I do mathematics in my free time.
Is it possible to publich some article in some journal, if I am not connected to any university or research institute?(I am aware about review process in mathematical journals)

Comment: I don't see why not.

Comment: Would you consider *on demand* pubblishing? That would be a nice way, but may not fit at best your purposes ("academic" research). As @Test123 says in his answer, if you reconsider PhD studies, there you would also have (tipically) a faculty covering the costs.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can. But since you want to publish something maybe it would be better to consider re-entering a PhD program in order to spend more time doing math. There you will have more opportunities to do research and publish your work.

Comment: I think about reentering PhD program. But, I'm over 30. currently I work as some kind of analyst for mathematical problems in industry (computations, signal processing) with some programming. So I like my job, but a lot of people told me something like: "You are scientist inside".